# How to compute the self-capacitance of a conductive shape?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, voltage, conductors

*(Depending on the answers given, this question might be better suited for Math.SE, but I don't think so.)*

I recently learnt about the notion of self-capacitance of a conductive shape, which now seems quite intuitive for me (else how would there be deflection in CRT tubes, given the low capacitance between the plates themselves.)

As an exercise, I set out to find the capacitance of a conductive circular arc of metal spanning from $\theta = -\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$, and of radius $R$.

## Attempt

We wish to find $C = Q/V$, and use the definition of Coulomb potential on a continuous distribution of charge :
$$
V = \frac{-1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int_S{\frac{\lambda(S)}{d}dS}
$$
With $d$ the distance between the point at which we wish to measure the potential and $dS$. Filling out (and using polar coordinates) we have :
$$
V(\alpha, r) = \frac{-1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\lambda(\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2 + R^2 -2rR\cos(\theta - \alpha)}}d\theta$$
We know the potential on the plate, $V$, and are only interested in it. So, put in $r = R$ and there is :
$$
V(\alpha) = V = \frac{-1}{4\sqrt2\pi\varepsilon_0R}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{\frac{\lambda(\theta)}{\sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta - \alpha)}} d\theta}
$$

I am stuck from there, only knowing that $\lambda$ is an even function (by symmetry). We also know that it must have a $0$ at $\theta - \alpha = 0$ so the integral converges. I feel like we *shouldn't care* about $\lambda$ itself, but its integral, the charge, which we know ($\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\lambda d\theta = Q$).

How to proceed? Is my method even correct at all ? How does one go about computing the self-capacitance of a 1D, 2D or even 3D conductive shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note*: Why the minus sign in your first equation?

Yes, maybe you're right. Once properly defined as to its physical
aspects, your problem is exquisitely mathematical.

The example you chose isn't easy, but the general approach is the same
in any case. It's a classical problem of 19-th century mathematical
physics. The trick is to reason in the reverse way wrt your approach.

Instead af writing an equation for potential as a function of charge
distribution, start from the (much simpler) assumption that $V$ is
constant on conductor's surface. Morover you know that in the empty
space around it $V$ satisfties Laplace equation:
$$\nabla^2 V = 0.$$

You have still to assign boundary conditions. At infinity $V=0$ as
usual. On the conductor, $V=V_0$ where $V_0$ is an arbitrary constant.
Since Laplace equation is linear and homogeneous, you know that its
solution will be proportional to $V_0$.

Here the problem becomes strictly mathematical: how to find *the*
solution (general theorems ensure it's unique).

Let's jump forward, supposing we've found the solution, in some way.
So we know $V(x,y,z)$ in all space outside the conductor and also on
its surface, where $V=V_0$. Now we may come back to physics. We know that 
$$\vec E = -\vec\nabla V$$
and that on conductor's surface 
$$\sigma = \epsilon_0\, E_n.$$
Then compute $E_n$ and $\sigma$. Integrate the latter on the surface,
and you get total charge $Q$. And here you are:
$$C = {Q \over V_0}.$$